# Am I missing something or is this not right way to declare event?

Tags: c#

I came across this piece of code. It works, but is it not against the .net event declaration guidelines?

```
public event Action SessionTimeout;
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? Can you please explain to me?

Comment: @Krumelur: See Nicole Calinoiu answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is that a .NET event uses a delegate that takes two parameters: the sender and the event arguments.  However, this is an API convention, not a requirement.  You may declare an event of any delegate type.

Answer (score 3):

While it is against standard C# practice, it is not an invalid event decleration.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to:

```
public event Action SessionTimeout = delegate {};
```

So you don't have to check for null before raising it.  I assume the potential extra CPU cycle this will cause won't affect your performance :)